# iOS 9 RTL navigation issue

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, ios9

I'm having issues to adopt RTL in my app that will be displayed well on both iOS 9 and 8.

I created a custom UITableViewCell with a UILabel as presented[image]:

In both iOS 9 & 8, when I ran my in a RightToLeft language the labels aligns to the right as expected.

[image]

when i push a new ViewController with the navigationController the navigation direction of the UINavigaitonController is different in iOS9 & 8,
in iOS 9 the navigation direction is to the left:
[image]

and in iOS 8 the navigation direction is to the right:
[image]

I want that by Label on the Cell will be aligned according to the navigationController push animation direction.

so the result on iOS 8 will be as presented, but I still want to keep the respect language direction attribute in the constraint.

does any one knows how the resolve this issue?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve it, is just to disable the RTL support, so on both RTL and LTR the result would be the same.

If you want to do it this way, do something like this:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
    [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
}
```